# Passing content of web page as string argument in shell_exec()

Tags: php, shell-exec

If I pass string content then it works fine and on submit it shows me result.
But when I pass the content of webpage received using `escapeshellarg(strip_tags($text));`. It shows nothing on the screen.

```
<?php
//sent has value "http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html"
$url=$_POST['sent'];
$text = file_get_contents($url);
$temp=escapeshellarg(strip_tags($text));
//$temp="one two two"; If I pass $temp with string content it gives result
echo $temp;  //Echo $temp shows content of webpage 
$output=shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/Modular/x '$temp'");
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: From the manual page for `escapeshellarg()` (emphasis mine): "`escapeshellarg()` **adds single quotes around a string** and quotes/escapes any existing single quotes allowing you to pass a string directly to a shell function and having it be treated as a single safe argument."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for comming here:

I got the answer:

```
<?php
//sent has value "http://www.paulgraham.com/herd.html"
$url=$_POST['sent'];
$text = file_get_contents($url);
$temp=escapeshellarg(strip_tags($text));
$output=shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/Modular/x " . $temp);
echo $output;
?>
```